# Is this a bug in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
    {
        NSLog(@"resign active");
    }

    - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
    {
        NSLog(@"background");  
    }

    - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
    {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
    {
        NSLog(@"Active");
    }

    - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
    {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }
```

When I do a four finger swipe to the left(dont completely change the application) I can see the logs  `resign active` and then move the four finger to the right `Active`.

If I do four finger swipe to the top, I can see `resign active`. After that if I do a four finger swipe to the right(without actually dismissing the lowerbar where you see all the running apps), I dont see `active`.

Is this a bug?

Comment: Why would you expect to see `"Active"` if you four-finger swipe to the right with the bottom bar showing? Your app isn't becoming active.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Your app hasn't really become active again, right? When you're looking at the task-switcher view, no app is active.